# Closing a getContentResolver Cursor

Tags: android

I am populating a `Cursor` by calling `getContentResolver` as follows in my `onCreate` method:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "oid, name, flag");
```

The `Cursor` is used when creating an instance of a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

On the query keyword (in line of code above), I am receiving the following warning:

> The cursor should be freed up after use with #close

I have tried to close this `Cursor` at the very end of my `onCreate` method, after instantiating my `SimpleCursorAdapter` class, but this makes the application crash.

Where and when should I close the `Cursor`?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using the Cursor for your SimpleCursorAdapter, closing it after calling the `setAdapter()` would prevent the adapter from accessing the data. Therefore you need to find another place to close it, perhaps in the activity tear down life cycle stages, such as `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestory()`. (My suggestion is to close the Cursor in the `onStop()` becuase it's guaranteed to get called).